# How to divide headings background-color into three different colours in html table

Tags: html, css, pandas, dataframe

I generate a report from the pandas Data Frame. I need to divide headings into 3 sections. This is what my DF looks like:

```
| A | B | C | D  | E | F  |
|11 |10 |9,7|-2,3|802|64,4|
|24 |10 |9,1|0,2 |725|66,1|
|19 |20 |9,9|3,91|798|58,3|
```

Right now my headings have the same background colour but I need to divide them into 3 different sections. Headers A and B should have the same background colour lest say for example blue, headers C and D should have the colour green, and headers E and F should have the colour yellow. How to do that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you not add unique classes to them and then apply different css for them?

Comment: I import the whole DataFrame using `df.to_html` that's why I need to modify the table using style statement. I don't make this table in HTML, I import DF. That's why I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) and a dictionary to map the column names to their color:

```
colors = {'A': 'blue', 'B': 'blue',
          'C': 'green', 'D': 'green',
          'E': 'yellow', 'F': 'yellow'
         }

df.style.set_table_styles(
   [{
       'selector': f'th.col{i}',
       'props': [('background-color', color)]
   } for i, color in enumerate(df.columns.map(colors))
   ])
```

If you have a MultiIndex and further need to select the level, use `f'th.level0.col{i}'`

[image]

##### variant by position

```
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']
N = len(colors) # 3

df.style.set_table_styles(
   [{
       'selector': f'th.level0.col{i}',
       'props': [('background-color', colors[i//(df.shape[1]//N)])]
   } for i in range(df.shape[1])
   ])
```

Comment: This works really well, but can I use HTML colours? Blue, green yellow these colours were just an example.

Comment: Yes of course: `'#60B2E8'` for example